# Why is this printing 'None' in the output?

Tags: python, nonetype

I have defined a function as follows:

```
def lyrics():
    print "The very first line"
print lyrics()
```

However why does the output return `None`:

```
The very first line
None
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Because there are **two print statements**. First is inside function and second is outside function. When a function doesn't return anything, it implicitly returns `None`.

Use `return` statement at end of function to return value.

e.g.:

Return `None`.

```
>>> def test1():
...    print "In function."
... 
>>> a = test1()
In function.
>>> print a
None
>>> 
>>> print test1()
In function.
None
>>> 
>>> test1()
In function.
>>>
```

Use return statement

```
>>> def test():
...   return "ACV"
... 
>>> print test()
ACV
>>> 
>>> a = test()
>>> print a
ACV
>>>
```

Comment: Hey can you tell me what is wrong the code? it's only returning last digit 
def another(n):
 rev = 0
 while(n>=0):
  rem=n%10
  rev = (10*rev)+ n%10
  n //= 10  
  return rev
print another(2154)
output:4

Comment: @def_0101: ok, What you are doing? reverse number??

Comment: yes reverse integers

Comment: @def_0101:  `def another(n): 
    rev = 0 
    while(n!=0): 
        rev = rev*10 + n%10 
        n //= 10
    return rev `

check .. adding explanation in next comment.

Comment: @def_0101: 
For Reverse, we need to get digit from number by last to first and crate new number by adding these digit with multiple of 0, 10, 100, 1000...
1. How to get last digit: Use `%` operation to get last digit that you done.
2.  Decrease input number by `/`dividing 10, this also you done.
3.  Create reverse number by add result of `%` operation to reverse number which is multiple of 10.
    
Let me know

Comment: still it's not working Thanks for the explanation i understood the logic behind reversing integer actually there might be a fault of while loop

Comment: @def_0101: email me your code vivekbsable@gmail.com..  Check where you write `return` statement? it should be outside of `while` loop.

Comment: [Here is the pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/M8ZgqQAs) well it is pretty inside the loop

Comment: @def_0101:  `return rev` must be outside of while loop.  Code is returning from the while because return is inside while loop..

Comment: SyntaxError: return outside function Lol

Comment: @def_0101 :) http://pastebin.com/VrLjuDuq  Check this

Comment: worked flawlessly !  actually i wrote it outside the function well I  gotta practice hard to get over with indentation errors   Thanks again

Answer (score 19):

Because of double print function. I suggest you to use `return` instead of `print` inside the function definition.

```
def lyrics():
    return "The very first line"
print(lyrics())
```

**OR**

```
def lyrics():
    print("The very first line")
lyrics()
```

Comment: is there any other way by using print statement ?

Comment: just `lyrics()` would be enough.

Comment: Thanks () i'm noob and very new to programming