# Function returns None under message

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I'm working on a login app in python, and i wrote this function:

```
def register_login():
    user_choice = input(print("Would you like to login or register?"))
    user_choice.lower()
    if user_choice == "login":
        print("You will be redirected to the login window.")
    elif user_choice == "register":
        print("You will be redirected to the registration window.")
```

But whenever i call this function the message gets printed with the value None under it.
Is there a way to get rid of the None message?

Comment: There must be more to it? How are you calling register_login?

Comment: Yes there is, I would like to say that I'm a total newbie to programming and this is my first training project. I know that the naming is not very accurate.

Comment: Yes there is. Do not call it with `print(register_login())` your function returns nothing so it returns None implicitly See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28812883/7505395) answer of the dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are calling it like this

`print(register_login())` because `register_login()` returns None.

You could return the values and print it like this.

```
def register_login():
    user_choice = input(print("Would you like to login or register?"))
    user_choice.lower()       
    if user_choice == "login":
        return "You will be redirected to the login window."
    elif user_choice == "register":
        return "You will be redirected to the registration window."

print(register_login())
```

Alternatively just call it with out the print()

```
register_login()
```

---

Side note - this line does nothing.

```
user_choice.lower()
```

you would want to replace it with.

```
user_choice = user_choice.lower()
```

or

```
user_choice = input("Would you like to login or register?").lower()
```

Comment: please accept my answer if it helped you