# Why is the output of this script a list of None?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know this is a simple question, but I would like to know why it is printing `None`. It just prints None when coding it directly from my terminal. If I write the same code in a file or in a online Python compiler and then run it, I don't get the same output.

Coding directly from my terminal:

```
>>> b = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
>>> [print(a) for a in b]
(1, 2)
(3, 4)
(5, 6)
[None, None, None]
```

Running in a Python Online Compiler:

[image]

Running Python file:

[image]

I know it is not the same array, but it is the same logic.

```
b = ([100.64188563286582, 101.64188563286582], [-1.0626228, -0.8626228], [-5.0, -15.0], [-float('inf'), float('inf')], [float('inf'), float('inf')], [-float('inf'), float('inf')], [-float('inf'), float('inf')])

[print(a) for a in b]
```

Comment: Please replace your images with pasted code (as a text).

Comment: You probably want to remove the print statement from the list comprehension. What you get is first the print output, then a list of the return values of the print calls.

Comment: And there is an answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28812851/why-is-this-printing-none-in-the-output

Comment: I edited the post with the code

Comment: Basically it's because function `print` returns None. Most statements executed in the interacive interpreter (your terminal) prints returned results.

Comment: @polalas Only to some extent. There still remain screen capture of your code. Not cool.

Comment: @pfabri I put the screen capture just to show the output, that was the idea

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is this printing 'None' in the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28812851/why-is-this-printing-none-in-the-output)

Answer (score 2):

`[print(a) for a in b]` results in a list of `print()` objects. As you can verify simply by `print(print())`, printing a list of `print()` objects will display a list of `None`

Comment: There is no such thing as a "`print` object" - `print` is not a class.

Answer (score 0):

Use without `print()` , as `print(print())` inner print not return any thing so that at last it gives `None`

```
>>>b=[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
>>>[a for a in b]
>>>[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

output:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```