# Return All the Element of a List Without Using Range in Python

Tags: python

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

def allElementsSingleRow(lst):
    for i in lst:
        print(i, end= " ")

print(allElementsSingleRow(lst))
```

`print(allElementsSingleRow(lst))` is always printing `None`. How can I fix my code to not print this?

Comment: Function allElementsSingleRow returns None so that's why you're printing None at the end.  Just use: `allElementsSingleRow(lst)` (i.e. without the print)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is this printing 'None' in the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28812851/why-is-this-printing-none-in-the-output)

Comment: Python functions can return a single value. This means you need to decide what it means to "return all the elements of a list". One way to do that is to return a list of elements...but you're starting with a list of elements, so what do you actually want your function to do?

Answer (score 1):

You're printing the elements and not returning anything. Either don't print the output of the function, or use a [generator](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/) function if you want to do something like this.

Not Printing the Output of the Function:

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

def allElementsSingleRow(lst):
    for i in lst:
        print(i, end= " ")

allElementsSingleRow(lst)
```

Using a generator

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

def allElementsSingleRow(lst):
    for i in lst:
        yield i

for element in allElementsSingleRow(lst):
    print(element, end=" ")
```

Comment: Curious why you want `allElementsSingleRow` at all...why not `for element in lst:`?

Comment: @Mark you don't have to use a generator like this, it is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

A list already contains all of its elements, so if your function is just supposed to return all the elements in the list, as a new list, that's simply the `copy` function:

```
def allElementsSingleRow(lst):
    return lst.copy()

print(allElementsSingleRow(lst))  
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

If your function is supposed to return all of the elements in the list as a single space-separated string, that's the `join` function:

```
def allElementsSingleRow(lst):
    return " ".join(lst)

print(allElementsSingleRow(lst))
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are again printing while calling the function and that function returns None. So if we use `print(allElementsSingleRow(lst))`  it will also print None at the end
You can just make the call to your function and it is done.

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

def allElementsSingleRow(lst):
    for i in lst:
        print(i, end= " ")

allElementsSingleRow(lst) # no need of print(allElementsSingleRow(lst))
```