# How can I remove the 'none' out of the output?

Tags: python, list

I was supposed to make a diamond out of this and I have successfully done so but I have a problem. Here is my code

```
k = 7
def triangle(k):
    a = (2*k) -1
    k = 3
    for x in range(0,a+1):
        if x % 2 != 0:
            f = int((a - x)/2)
            g = f"{'#'*f}{'*'*x}{'#'*f}"
            print(g)
def diamond(k):
    a = (2 * k) - 1
    k = 3
    for x in reversed(range(0, a)):
        if x % 2 != 0:
            f = int((a - x) / 2)
            g = f"{'#' * f}{'*' * x}{'#' * f}"
            print(g)

l = f"{triangle(k)}\n{diamond(k)}"
print(l)
```

Along with the diamond, there are also two 'none' appearing underneath like this in the output..

```
######*######
#####***#####
####*****####
###*******###
##*********##
#***********#
*************
#***********#
##*********##
###*******###
####*****####
#####***#####
######*######
None
None
```

How can I print the output without including the none in the output??

Comment: Neither functions return anything, so capturing and printing their calls makes little sense

Comment: `triangle(k)` and `diamond(k)` both don't return anything (i.e. they return `None`). Instead, they contain print statements. So when you do `print(l)` you're printing `"None\nNone"`

Comment: What's the point of `l = f"{triangle(k)}\n{diamond(k)}"; print(l)`? Calling `triangle` and `diamond` already prints the results

Comment: I tried not printing it but the result is wrong though, like the figure is distorted when I try it... is there any part of my code that I should change to make sure the 'none' doesnt get printed??

Comment: `triangle(k) ; print() ; diamond(k)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is this printing 'None' in the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28812851/why-is-this-printing-none-in-the-output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a modification on [@schwobasggl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69542110/10237506), using *f-strings* that works in Python 3.6+

```py
def up_and_down(n):  # 1,2, ..., n, ..., 2, 1
    return (*range(1, n), *range(n, 0, -1))


def diamond(n, pad='#', fill='*'):
    w = (2 * n) - 1

    for i in up_and_down(n):
        # you can also use the below, but it's slightly less performant:
        # fill_w = len(up_and_down(i))
        fill_w = i * 2 - 1

        print(f'{fill * fill_w:{pad}^{w}}')
```

It should end up with the same result:

```py
>>> diamond(7)

######*######
#####***#####
####*****####
###*******###
##*********##
#***********#
*************
#***********#
##*********##
###*******###
####*****####
#####***#####
######*######
```

If you want to print a triangle (the top half of the diamond), you can iterate over only the first half of `up_and_down` in the outer loop. Another way is to just iterate over `range(1, n+1)` - that is `1, 2, 3` for `n=3` - as shown below:

```py
def triangle(n, pad='#', fill='*'):
    w = (2 * n) - 1

    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        print(f'{fill * (i * 2 - 1):{pad}^{w}}')
```

It looks like that should now work to print just the top half of the diamond above:

```py
>>> triangle(7)

######*######
#####***#####
####*****####
###*******###
##*********##
#***********#
*************
```

#### Links for reference

- [How to pad/fill a string by a variable using f-strings](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/how-to-pad-fill-string-by-variable-python)
- [A Guide to f-strings in Python](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)
- [String alignment in f-strings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-alignment-in-python-f-string/)

Comment: your code is great, but what if I want to print the top half only, aka I want to print a triangle as well under -- def triangle(n): so is there a way for me to halve the diamond??

Comment: @Nutnicha hmm, that should be possible with a slight change. let me take a look.

Comment: yepp, pls lemme know when u modified it, thx a lott

Comment: @Nutnicha I updated answer above with a `triangle` function you can use to print the top half of a diamond

Comment: Thank you very very much

Comment: @Nutnicha no problem! remember to also accept an answer if you find it helpful, so that it can help others who might be searching for a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the functions already prints the output. Printing the return values (`None`) makes little sense. That being said, this can be tremendously simplified:

```
def up_and_down(n):  # 1,2, ..., n, ..., 2, 1
    return (*range(1, n), *range(n, 0, -1))

def diamond(n):
    for i in up_and_down(n):
        print((n-i)*'#', *('*' for _ in up_and_down(i)), (n-i)*'#', sep='') 

>>> diamond(7)
######*######
#####***#####
####*****####
###*******###
##*********##
#***********#
*************
#***********#
##*********##
###*******###
####*****####
#####***#####
######*######
```

Comment: where should I put this in my code though?? Like can u please copy and paste my code and then show where to put your piece of code please??