# im trying to print my student info which it does but prints none as well. why?

Tags: python

i print my student info i get that but i get a none after that i dont understand why? and i tried return but it only does it for the first value in "def get_info".
Output:
10
saif
14
5
None
ahmed
48
20
None

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age, yearsplay):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.yearsplay = yearsplay

    def get_info(self):
        print(self.name) 
        print( self.age)
        print(self.yearsplay) 

class Course:
    def __init__(self, Maxstudents):
        self.Maxstudents = Maxstudents
        self.Students = []

        print(Maxstudents)

    def add_students(self, Student):
        if len(self.Students) < self.Maxstudents:
            self.Students.append(Student)
            print(Student.get_info())



s1 = Student("saif", 14, 5)
s2 = Student("ahmed", 48, 20)
c = Course(10)
c.add_students(s1)
c.add_students(s2)
```

Comment: What does get_info return in your opinion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is this printing 'None' in the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28812851/why-is-this-printing-none-in-the-output)

Comment: As you can see this is a duplicate of a duplicate. Maybe try searching here next time first

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the output of my function printing out "None"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053652/why-is-the-output-of-my-function-printing-out-none)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line, print(Student.get_info()) calls get_info, and it returns None. So, None will be printed.